# How can you change the KivyMD file explorer in python so that a double click opens a directory

Tags: python, kivy

So I am working on a file explorer for a project in school and I am using the file explorer widget that comes built into KivyMD. The problem is the current code of the widget makes it so it opens a directory when you click on it once in the icon view. I need it to be that a single click selects a directory and double click then opens it. I tried checking for double touch but it doesn't seem to work. Is there anyway to get this working. I am really not that advanced in python or kivy.

Source code for kivyMD file explorer: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD/master/kivymd/uix/filemanager.py

'''

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a hack that does what I think you want. At the top of your main `.py` file, add the following lines (should be before any other imports):

```
from kivy.config import Config
# calculate a time delta that is slightly longer than the maximum time for a double tap
dtt = (int(Config.get('postproc', 'double_tap_time')) + 50) / 1000.0
```

Then use the following `MyMDFileManager` rather than `MDFileManager`:

```
class MyMDFileManager(MDFileManager):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyMDFileManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.single_tap_trigger = None
        self.last_touch = None

    def select_dir_or_file(self, path):
        if self.last_touch is None or not self.last_touch.is_double_tap:
            # schedule single tap process to happen after a possible second tap of a double tap
            self.single_tap_trigger = Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.do_single_tap, path), dtt)
        elif self.last_touch.is_double_tap:
            if self.single_tap_trigger:
                # this is a double tap, so cancel single tap scheduled process
                self.single_tap_trigger.cancel()
                self.single_tap_trigger = None

            # do double tap proessing
            self.do_double_tap(path)
        else:
            # just clean up
            if self.single_tap_trigger:
                self.single_tap_trigger.cancel()
                self.single_tap_trigger = None

    def do_double_tap(self, path):
        print('double tap\n')
        super(MyMDFileManager, self).select_dir_or_file(path)

    def do_single_tap(self, path, dt):
        print('single tap\n')
        self.select_path(path)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.last_touch = touch
        return super(MyMDFileManager, self).on_touch_down(touch
```

When a single click is received, the normal single click processing is delayed (using `Clock.schedule_once()`) by a time that is slightly longer than the maximum time allowed between taps of a double tap.

If another click occurs fast enough to be a double tap, then the scheduled single tap processing is cancelled, and the double tap processing is initiated.